# pip install can't find the latest version advertised by pip search

Tags: pip

Trying to install the latest version of pandas on my ubuntu 16.04 through `pip install`

If I read well the result of this command:

`python3 -m pip search pandas`

```
...
pandas (0.25.3)                     - Powerful data structures for data analysis, time series, and statistics
  INSTALLED: 0.24.2
  LATEST:    0.25.3
...
```

I should be able to install version 0.25.3 of that package.

I tried

- `pip install --upgrade pandas --user`, which tells me that I already have the latest version
- `pip install --upgrade --upgrade-strategy eager pandas  --user`, that installed up-to-date versions of dependencies, but pandas is still 0.24.2
- `python3 -m pip install pandas==0.25.3 --user` which tells me that specific version can't be found, and provides me with a very long list of available versions stopping indeed at version 0.24.2

Am I misinterpreting something ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the latest Python 3 available by default with Ubuntu 16.04 ([3.5.1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/python/python3)), it isn't compatible with the 0.25.x release of pandas according to the [release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/whatsnew/v0.25.0.html). You can see some related discussion [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27558).

To see this from pip, you can run the install command using `-v` and pip will indicate that some links are being ignored because of an incompatible Python version.

You have a few options:

1. Use a PPA that provides more recent Python 3 versions for 16.04, like [deadsnakes](https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)
2. Use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)

Comment: thanks for the tip, -v is indeed really informative. Strangely pandas 0.25.3 became available meanwhile, but next time I have a similar problem I'll be better armed.